# FileNotFound when opening picture in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, storage

I'm building an app that needs to open a picture made by the camera. I followed the official android [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) and did like they said, but I keep getting this error message:

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_test_-1259913402.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

My code looks like this:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            System.err.println("An error occurred: " + ex);
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //try {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            System.out.println(imageBitmap);
            testViewer.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            //bc = new BarDecoder(imageBitmap);
        //} catch (NotFoundException | FormatException e){
          //  System.err.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        //}
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cancelled!");
    }
}

public void scanImage(View view){
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = "test";
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("Created!!");
    return image;
}
```

I can see that the pictures are indeed created when using a file explorer, but my app can't find them. I also included these permissions in my manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by removing the "file:" from mCurrentPhotoPath. Android's official guide says this is necessary, but apparently this doesn't work!